# Why menu hamburger won't expand unless it's the home page

Tags: mobile, hugo

Here is my website:

https://jazz3.netlify.app/

If you open it up on mobile, the menu opens fine on the home page. For other pages (for e.g. https://jazz3.netlify.app/contact), the menu just won't open on mobile. I am at my wits end and have no idea why this is happening. I originally built the site with Webflow, then exported the code and changed it so it's using Hugo's framework.

You can see the code here: https://github.com/janezhgw/ja-z
If you're unfamiliar with Hugo, you can find the css file in 'static' folder. To find the code for the navigation, it's in 'layout' > 'partials' > 'nav'.